# Which free and opensource NoSQL database provides feature for creating groups/buckets of documents?

Tags: database, nosql

I am learning CouchDB. As I understand it, documents in the database cannot be grouped into categories, such as, for example, all receipt documents can be put into a receipt bucket, invoices can be put into invoice bucket etc.

Are there any free and opensource NoSQL databases that provide this feature of grouping documents according to category?